# Vector potential of a uniformly magnetised sphere

Tags: vectors, electromagnetism

I am in the process of trying to find out the potential of a uniformly magnetised sphere with radius $a$. What I need to work out is the following:

$\int\int\frac{d\vec{S} }{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}$

where I am directing the $z$-axis along $\vec{r}$

and $
d\vec S= (\sin θ \cos ψ \vec{i}+\sin θ \sin ψ \vec j+cos θ \vec k)a^
2
\sin θdθdψ$, $\vec {r'}=a\sin\theta\cos\psi\vec{i}+a\sin\theta\sin\psi\vec j+a\cos\theta\vec k$

I have gotten as far as working out the modulus to be $\sqrt{a^2+r^2-2ar\cos\theta}=R$

I think I have to convert $d\vec S$ somehow but I am really stuck and need help please.

Comment: This fits better to Physics.SE https://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I asked it here and they said I should ask it here. Please help I'm desperate.